How did 동내(洞內) become nativized to 동네?
The Wiktionary entry (last edited March 2021) for 동네 says:

Nativisation of the Sino-Korean term 동내 (洞內, dongnae, “within the district”).

What caused 애 to change to 에? And more generally, what causes "nativization of Sino-Korean terms" exactly?
Is there just a tendency for words to change 애 to 에 (more generally, maybe for vowels to raise)? It seems that might be the case if I look at the Wiktionary category for Nativized Sino-Korean words, e.g. 가게 < 가개 < 가가 (假家).

https://hangyo.com/news/article.html?no=52918#:~:text=%E3%80%8C%EB%8F%99%EB%84%A4%E3%80%8D%EB%8A%94%20'%EC%9E%90%EA%B8%B0%EA%B0%80,%EC%A0%80%EB%8F%99%EB%84%A4'%20%EB%A5%BC%20%EB%9C%BB%ED%95%9C%EB%8B%A4.

Because Koreans don't perceive it as a 한자어.
The shift has been towards easier pronunciation in Korean language usage. Research on this topic can be found by searching "한국어 단어 어휘 연구" on Google, although I don't recommend it. This field is studied in Korean language and literature departments (국어국문학과).
For example, despite Japan's cultural connection to Chinese characters, there is no Japanese word utilizing 假家. Instead, Japan uses 店 (mise, shop) rather than 假家. When Koreans use the word "가게," they typically do not associate it with the Chinese character 假家.
Each country expresses words primarily in its own language rather than using Chinese characters. Therefore, 한자-derived words are evolving and changing over time.

I guess the reason I ask is, I was under the impression that Hanja words were borrowed from Middle Chinese and then after regular sound changes became their current forms. So I'm thinking there'd have to be things like dialect mixing in order for the word to drift from its "Hanja" pronunciation. I don't see how being perceived as a native term would change how its pronunciation evolves.

This is a very difficult question.If you're a researcher who traces the history of words, you would know the process of change. The link I posted above said that 동네 has lost the meaning of 內. In my opinion, you don't need to connect 동네 with 동내.
